# How To Have A Single Interface Return Different Data Types?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

In a nutshell, I want to use a single interface, `IProducer`, to create an object, `IProduct`. `IProduct` will have *different components* depending on which interface created it. The `IProduct` class will then be used by the `IConsumer` interface. The correct `IConsumer` class should be used (I do not want to do type checking myself) based on the derived type of `IProduct`.

I would essentially like to use the Strategy pattern (different behaviors behind a single interface), but with the added ability to return an object specific to the derived interface used. I want to abide by the Open/Close principle and not alter any of these existing classes when more functionality is added.

I would like to accomplish something like this (I'm sure the syntax is wrong somewhere but bear with me):

```
class IProduct {
    public:
        int intData;
};

class ProductA : public IProduct {
    public:
        float floatData;
};

class ProductB : public IProduct {
    public:
        bool boolData;
};

class IProducer {
  public:
    virtual IProduct* produce(void) = 0;
};

class ProducerA : public IProducer {
  public:
    IProduct* produce(void) {
        return new ProductA;
    }
};

class ProducerB : public IProducer {
  public:
    IProduct* produce(void) {
        return new ProductB;
    }
};

class IConsumer {
    public:
        virtual void consume(IProduct* prod) = 0;
};

class ConsumerA : public IConsumer {
    public:
        void consume(IProduct* prod) {
        //I want to access the float!
    }
};

class ConsumerB : public IConsumer {
    public:
        void consume(IProduct* prod) {
        //I want to access the bool!
    }
};

void main() {

    IProducer* producer = ProducerFactory::create("ProducerA");

    IProduct* product = producer->produce();

    IConsumer* consumer = ConsumerFactory::create("ConsumerA");

    consumer->consume(product); //I would like the correct consumer to be used here to deal with the ProductA class
}
```

If you think there is a better way to go about this I'm all ears. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to limit a consumer to a specific kind (or kinds) of products, it sounds like you will want to use [`dyanmic_cast`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast).

Comment: I don't think there is any way to access data from `ProductA` in `ConsumerA::consume` when passing an `IProduct` by value, because only the `IProduct` part gets copied.

Comment: @typ1232 Yes it has to be a reference or pointer

Comment: I think I've read about this and it's called "slicing". I think I read that if you use pointers the derived class keeps its members but I'm not sure.

Comment: @trianta2 Yes, you must use pointers for this (sorry, missed that the first pass).  It should be `IProduct*` for both the return value and the function parameter.

Comment: @ZacHowland In this example `IProduct` is not polymorphic, so `dynamic_cast` cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer correction, however I didn't want the syntax itself to be examined here but rather the architecture of what I'm trying to achieve. In reality I would certainly use smart pointers. EDIT: Changed to pointers anyway.

Comment: May a template-based solution suit your needs? Something like [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @typ1232 Assuming the (ommitted) member functions are included (specifically, a virtual destructor) in the base and derived classes, [it is polymorphic](http://ideone.com/L7q3NE).

Comment: "I want to use ... to create an object" Have you looked at creational patterns? Builder, Factory

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a registry which maps `IProduct` implementations to the right `IConsumer` implementations. Basically its just an abstraction of a map:

```
class ConsumerRegistry
{
    std::map<size_t, std::shared_ptr<IConsumer>> m_consumers;

public:

    // we are not responsible for products, so lets allow plain ptrs here for more flexibility and less overhead
    std::shared_ptr<IConsumer> GetConsumer(IProduct* product)
    {
        auto it = m_consumers.find(typeid(product).hash_code());

        if (it == m_consumers.end())
            return nullptr;
        else
            return it->second;
    }

    template<typename P>
    void RegisterConsumer(std::shared_ptr<IConsumer> consumer)
    {
        m_consumers.emplace(typeid(P).hash_code(), consumer);
    }

    template<typename P>
    void UnregisterConsumer()
    {
        m_consumers.erase(typeid(P).hash_code());
    }
};
```

Either expose this class globally (e.g as singleton) or use it in the contexts where you need it. You register consumers like this:

```
reg.RegisterConsumer<ProductA>(new ConsumerA());
reg.RegisterConsumer<ProductB>(new ConsumerB());
```

We could also have a `virtual void Register(ConsumerRegistry& reg) = 0;` method inside `IConsumer` allowing for safer registering:

```
void ConsumerA::Register(ConsumerRegistry& reg, std::shared_ptr<IConsumer> self)
{
    IConsumer::Register<ProductA>(reg, self);
}

// Required for friendship, can be static:
template<typename T>
void IConsumer::Register(ConsumerRegistry& reg, std::shared_ptr<IConsumer> self)
{
    reg->RegisterConsumer<T>(self);
}

void ConsumberRegistry::RegisterConsumer(std::shared_ptr<IConsumer> consumer)
{
    consumer->Register(*this, consumer);
}
```

Make both `Register()` and the low-level `RegisterConsumer()` methods private and let `ConsumerRegistry` and `IConsumer` be friends. Can be used like this then:

```
reg.RegisterConsumer(new ConsumerA());
reg.RegisterConsumer(new ConsumerB());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I'm thinking of using. I'd appreciate any feedback.

I'm going to use the Visitor pattern and introduce the `ProductVisitor` class like so:

```
class IProductVisitor {
public:
    explicit IProductVisitor() {}
    virtual ~IProductVisitor(){}
    virtual void visitA(ProductA* model) = 0;
    virtual void visitB(ProductB* model) = 0;
};


class ProductTypeVisitor : public IProductVisitor {
    public:
        typedef enum {Unknown, A, B} ProductType;
        explicit ProductTypeVisitor() : modelType(Unknown) {}
        virtual ~ProductTypeVisitor(){}
        virtual void visitA(ProductA* product) {
            modelType = A;
        }

        virtual void visitB(ProductB* product) {
            modelType = B;
        }

        ProductType getProductType(void) {
            return modelType;
        }

        ProductType modelType;
};

class IProduct {
    public:
        IProduct() : intData(3) {}
        virtual ~IProduct(){}
        int intData;
        virtual void accept(IProductVisitor* v) = 0;
};

class ProductA : public IProduct {
    public:
        ProductA() : IProduct(), floatData(5.5) { }
        virtual ~ProductA(){}
        float floatData;
        void accept(IProductVisitor* v) {
            v->visitA(this);
        }
};

class ProductB : public IProduct {
    public:
        ProductB() : IProduct(),boolData(false) { }
        virtual ~ProductB(){}
        bool boolData;
        void accept(IProductVisitor* v) {
            v->visitB(this);
        }
};
```

When making my factory, `ConsumerFactor`, I will use the `ProductTypeVisitor` class to determine what class the product is, dynamically cast it correctly (based off of the state of the `enum`), and then return a consumer initialized with the correct product.

```
class ConsumerFactory {
public:
    explicit ConsumerFactory(void) {}

    IConsumer* createFromProduct(IProduct* product) {

        ProductTypeVisitor visitor;
        product->accept(&visitor);
        ProductTypeVisitor::ProductType productType = visitor.getProductType();

        IConsumer* consumerPtr;
        switch (productType) {
        case ProductTypeVisitor::A :
            consumerPtr =  new ConsumerA(dynamic_cast<ProductA*>(product));
            break;
        case ProductTypeVisitor::B :
            consumerPtr =  new ConsumerB(dynamic_cast<ProductB*>(product));
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Product type undefined. (throw exception)" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        return consumerPtr;
    }

private:
    ProductTypeVisitor visitor;

};
```

Finally, the code will look like this:

```
IProducer* producer = new ProducerA;

IProduct* product = producer->produce();

ConsumerFactory factory;

IConsumer* consumer = factory.createFromProduct(product);

consumer->consume();
```

Where the only thing that was ever specified, was `ProducerA`. Which, in my case, is the only thing that should be specified by the user. Also, I've isolated change areas to just two classes, the `ConsumerFactory`, and the `IProductVisitor` (which are very small changes to begin with).

If anyone could offer improvements or suggestions I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full solution (and maybe just a curiosity) but you can always do the tracking of types at compile time and use a bridging templated call to dispatch a product to the correct consumer.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class IProduct {
public:
  virtual ~IProduct() {}

  int intData;

  typedef T consumer;
};

class ConsumerA;

class ProductA : public IProduct<ConsumerA> {
public:
  float floatData;
};

class ConsumerB;

class ProductB : public IProduct<ConsumerB> {
public:
  bool boolData;
};

template <class P, class C>
void apply(P* product, C* consumer) {
  dynamic_cast<typename P::consumer*>(consumer)->consume(product);
}

template <class T>
class IConsumer {
public:
  virtual void consume(IProduct<T>* prod) = 0;
};

class ConsumerA : public IConsumer<ConsumerA> {
public:
  void consume(IProduct<ConsumerA>* prod) {
    //I want to access the float!
    std::cout << "ConsumerA" << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<ProductA*>(prod)->floatData << std::endl;
  }
};

class ConsumerB : public IConsumer<ConsumerB> {
public:
  void consume(IProduct<ConsumerB>* prod) {
    //I want to access the bool!
    std::cout << "ConsumerB" << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<ProductB*>(prod)->boolData << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto p_a = new ProductA;
  auto c_a = new ConsumerA;

  apply(p_a, c_a);

  auto p_b = new ProductB;
  auto c_b = new ConsumerB;

  apply(p_b, c_b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inheritance is lost here (dont know whether Its a requirement but I think so), as `IProduct<A>` is a completely different class than `IProduct<B>`; c++ is not java.

Comment: @Paranaix I'm not sure if I understand your comment. Inheritance is preserved where it's needed: between the `IProduct` interface and the actual product. Otherwise the `dynamic_cast` would fail. But, if a product that inherits from another product is of interest, this solution is not the best. Further, what do you mean by "c++ is not java"? A trivial interpretation is trivial...

Comment: in your example it is not possible to hold e.g a vector of `IProduct*`. Why? Because `IProduct<A>` is a different class than `IProduct<B>`. In Java however such a design would be possible as there an IProduct stays an IProduct no matter what type you pass to it thus the `c++ is not java`

Comment: @Paranaix Ah, good point. If one were to stick to this approach, one might then have to ecapsulate the dispatch in, for example, a functor and have a vector or those. But, as stated at the start of the answer, this might be more of a curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to solve a analogous issue. I ended up using [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (which `c++17` added to the language) to solve my problem. A single interface can return a `std::any` which you can cast back into the underlying type (via `std::any_cast`). In broad terms, `std::any` is like “hiding” types behind a `void*` pointer, but done in a type safe way, with full language and compiler support.

See:

- [std::any: How, when, and why](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdany-how-when-and-why/)
- [When should I use std::any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715219/when-should-i-use-stdany)
- Related topic [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).