# C++ type_info as template (typename) parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typename

Is there a way of using `const std::type_info&` as a template parameter in C++?

For example

```
template < typename T > class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    const std::type_info& type() const
    {
        return typeid(T);
    }
};

template < typename T > void Do()
{
    // Do whatever
}

int main()
{
    A<int> MyA;
    // Something like: Do<MyA.type()>(); or Do<typeid(MyA.type())>();
}
```

Comment: Short: No, `type_info` is an (non constexpr constructable) object. Why dont you go simply with the template arg (`T`)? If your intention is to provide different implementations for polymorphic classes at runtime you this might interesst you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317403/how-to-have-a-single-interface-return-different-data-types/21318361#21318361

Answer (score 3):

You can't use run-time type information as a compile-time template parameter.

In C++11, `decltype` can give you the static type of an expression:

```
Do<decltype(MyA)>();
```

Historically, the best you could do would be to use another function template to infer the type from its argument:

```
template <typename T> void Do(T const &) {Do<T>();}

Do(MyA);
```