# When should I use std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

Since C++17 `std::any` is introduced. One can now write code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <string>

int main () {
    const double d = 1.2;
    std::any var = d;
    const std::string str = "Hello World";
    var = str;
}
```

A double is assigned to the variable `var` and than a `std::string` was assigned  to it.

Why has `std::any` been introduced?

I think this is violating the `least astonishment rule`, because I find it hard to think of a situation, where this can be used to express more clearly, what I like to express.

Can somebody give me a good example, when `std::any` is beneficial.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-kepOD

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/10/04/stdany-how-when-and-why/

Comment: If you use `std::any` to obfuscate code, then sure it violates the least astonishment rule. If you use it as a safer `void*` (see the article T.C. linked to), it's anything but astonishing.

Comment: use `std::any` where in the past you would have used `void*`. Which is to say, ideally, almost nowhere.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3804.html

Comment: Will it be good alongside factory pattern?

Comment: Is there a typo? than->then
I try to fix it,but get "Edits must be at least 6 characters"

Comment: In my experience void* is used almost exclusively when interacting with c libraries / callbacks... and those can't be converted to std::any.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**When to Use**

`void*` as an extremely unsafe pattern with some limited use cases, `std::any` adds type-safety, and that’s why it has some real use cases.

**Some possibilities:**

- In Libraries - when a library type has to hold or pass anything without knowing the 
  set of available types.
- Parsing files - if you really cannot specify what are the supported
  types.
- Message passing.
- Bindings with a scripting language.
- Implementing an interpreter for a scripting language
- User Interface - controls might hold anything
- Entities in an editor
  ([ref](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/any.html?m=1))

Comment: "if you really cannot specify what are the supported types." Means reading "anything" into some kind of storage. OK. And how to use that data? If I have no idea what is contained in std::any, I have no idea how to handle that data. And if I know how to handle the data, I know the list of potential stored types. And that is std::variant made for. I can't catch the point... can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Klaus if the parsing code is generic and might not know all types as compile time (either supported types are dynamic or you don't want to create a dependency).

Comment: "*Implementing an interpreter for a scripting language*" is a very good example. Especially combined with "*Bindings with a scripting language*". I found it really convenient to use `std::any` when implementing a constrained Python interpreter.

Comment: @Klaus: The use case is when *some* code knows the type being stored, but that code isn’t responsible for the *lifetime* (including, perhaps, making copies) of that data.

Answer (score 9):

I would summarize it as classic "use when you cannot avoid it".

I can only think of non-performance-critical implementations of dynamically typed scripting languages to represent variables from the scripting world, but even that with a stretch ([Boost.Spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/) does it without, for both the parser and the runtime).

For everything else from parsers (e.g. [Boost.Spirit.X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html)) to library APIs (e.g. [ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html)) there would usually be a faster/better/more-specific alternative, as very few things are really "anything", most are more specific than that.

- `std::variant` and/or `std::optional` for "almost any value"
- `std::packaged_task` / `std::function` + lambdas for "callback with arguments", which would be a case of `void*` in C APIs.
- etc.

Specifically, I wouldn't blindly plug it as a replacement for a `void*`, as it [may allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878040/does-boostany-stdany-store-small-objects-in-place) memory on the heap, which can be deadly for high performance code.

Comment: May, but doesn't have to. The specification allows for small object optimization IUC.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I updated the answer with a link to the question dedicated to that. There is an answer there with per-compiler specifics. Please take a look.

Answer (score 7):

`std::any` is a *vocabulary* type.  When you need to store, well, some bit of anything, as a value you can use it.

There are a number of "first level" uses of it:

1. When interacting with scripting languages which themselves have such types, it is a natural fit.
2. When you have a property tree with highly polymorphic content, and the structure of the tree is decoupled from the producer and consumer of the tree.
3. When replacing the equivalent of a `void*` chunk of data being passed through an intermediate layer who really doesn't care what it is carrying.

It can also be used as a building block in other cases.  For example, `std::function` could choose to store its value in the `std::any`:

```
template<class R, class...Args>
struct func<R(Args...)> {
  mutable std::any state;
  R(*f)(std::any& state, Args&&...) = nullptr;
  template<class T>
  void bind(T&& t) {
    state = std::forward<T>(t);
    f = [](std::any& state, Args&&...args)->R {
      return std::any_cast<T&>(state)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
  R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return f(state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

that is a pretty small implementation of (most of) `std::function`.  Basically I've used `any` to type erase copy/move/destroy.

You can using this elsewhere for similar problems (where you are type-erasing some operation and also want to type erase copy/move/destroy), or [generalize it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38835747/1774667).

Comment: tbh, this type shouldn't  have been called `std::any`. It's.. `std::some(thing?)`

Comment: @swift you'll have to take that up with ... well, nobody, because it ain't changing.  But definitely not me.

Answer (score 2):

It's used in Wt, to provide a non-template interface for [tabular data](https://webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WAbstractItemModel.html#af77f707dd2340652717e7122cd7f4ffd).

There are conversions to string for builtin and Wt types, and you can register additional conversions by specialising [`Wt::any_traits`](https://webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/structWt_1_1any__traits.html). This allows anything to be displayed as an entry in a table, the view classes don't have to know anything about the types they are displaying.

Comment: can you please post a link to a code example that’s using these traits?

Comment: I don't have an example to hand. You can look in the Wt source for how it handles say `WDateTime`